# Log levels in Production

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I need to set logs levels on prod and i do understand that there are different log levels.

Can anyone suggest or recommend what is the right level of logs to be set on Production environment? If i turn the log level to `finest` it gives me all the logs, which is quite useful for developers to debug, but how do we manage them as there would be tons of logs generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*=info` is the most detailed recommended for production. `Fine, finer, finest` are trace level, they will generate lots of messages, and are recommended only for debugging and diagnosing problems. In case of problems you can always increase log level to finest in runtime without server restart.